# Dynamic Content in Exact Target using EmailAddress Profile Attribute

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I want to customize an email in ExactTarget using the target subscriber email in a rule to define the email content.
I created an static content, and when I tried to create the dynamic content I did not get any property in the attribute dropdowns. ( for this dynamic content I selected as "Data From" the "Profile Attribute").

I checked in "Profile Management" and I have Email and FullName as properties.

I have to change something to use Email property in the Dynamic content definition?

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Adriano. Is this related to Exacttarget? Your description doesn't at all sound familiar in terms of a regular instance of SalesForce. Clarifying what it's related to is much more likely to get you a helpful response. You can always add multiple tags to a post to help add that clarification and you're always able to edit your own posts (lower left of your post).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I updated the post to reflect this. Thanks